# When I add a hyperlink to my logo it ignores CSS sizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here's my code. Using bootstrap 4.1 framework:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img class="logo" src="logo2.png">
      <p>
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.logo { width: 50%; height: 50%;}
```

So I casually add a hyperlink on the image to my homepage like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a href="home.html"><img class="logo" src="logo2.png"></a>
        <p>
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the logo freaks out and becomes slanted and odd looking. I tried moving the link around the grid container but it's a no go. Also tried keeping the styling inline inside the `<img>` tag. Still a no no :(

Comment: What kind of CSS do you have for links?

Comment: I have color. Lemme remove it and see if that helps.

Update: Didn't work out. I checked any related styling and there's nothing beyond color. Even removing it didn't help out.

Comment: It's probably inheriting that scaling from a parent container. I don't work with Bootstrap enough to have all the stock classes memorized so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's difficult to translate *"the logo freaks out and becomes odd looking"* into web terms, so we can actually understand what you're describing.

Comment: @Kleio Will you be able to write the question with more regards to grammar? 
This is an international website where people write in english from all over the world and it would be much appreciated to read question in plain, clean, easy, understandable language.
Your english is at a `no, no` level at the moment.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thank you for the feedback. (Apologies, I'm new). In the future I'll definitely try to be more direct and specific!

Comment: @Adriano And the same. Feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` unit sets the width&height relative to the parent element's width&height.

First, define the width&height value for parent element *(in your code = `a`)* and add `logo` class into it. *(see example below)*

```css
.logo {
  width: 50%; /* parent element's width */
  height: 50% /* parent element's height */
}

.logo>img {
  width: 100%; /* img's width */
  height: 100% /* img's height */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a href="home.html" class="logo"><img src="logo2.png" /></a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```